# Redux: Approach to store from reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get the store from the reducer.
i saw the redux architecture is not supporting sharing between reducers.
but its really needed in my case.

```
const initState = {
  schemas: [],
};


const myReducer = (state , action) => {
  state = state || initState;

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'redux-form/CHANGE':
      const schemaId = getStore().context.schema;
      let modifier = state.schemas.get(schemaId);
      modifier[action.key] = action.value;

      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
};
```

my app reducers:

```
const iceApp = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  context,
  myReducer,
});
```

thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add reducer functions to any level of your state, consider:

```
const complexReducer = (state, action) {
   const {context, myReducer} = state;

   switch (action.type) {
   case 'redux-form/CHANGE':
      // do something with myReducer

      return {context, myReducer};
   default:
      return state;
   }
}

// a simple utility function to call reducers in sequence on the same state
function composeReducers(...reducers) {
    return (state, action) => reducers.reduceRight((acc, reducer) => reducer(acc, action), state);
}

const iceApp = composeReducers(complexReducer, combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    context,
    myReducer,
}));
```

This will apply the `complexReducer` to the whole state coming from the simple reducers.

A different approach is to access `context` in the action and pass it as payload of the action.

```
const changeAction = ... // the redux-form/change action

const changeActionWithContext = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
   const state = getState();
   const schemaId = state.context.schema;

   dispatch(changeAction(schemaId));
}
```

I don't now `redux-form` so I don't know whether it's possible or not to add custom payload to `redux-form` actions.